# countdown timer not working right

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am using this countdown timer and trying to get it to show the proper days but for some reason it says 13 days when I know it should be around 111 days.

Here is the page: http://co.isafyi.com/

```
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#countdown').countDown({
                        targetDate: {
                            'day':      28,
                            'month':    2,
                            'year':     2015,
                            'hour':     23,
                            'min':      59,
                            'sec':      0
                        },
                        omitWeeks: true
                    });
                });
```

Comment: What is the countdown widget?  It isn't part of jQuery.  Can you add a link to where it can be studied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 113 days. You are missing one digit field for days. Just add

```
<div class="digit white">0</div>
```

to your `<div class="ctnDigits">` in `<div class="dash days_dash">`